# Create kafka connector with the name which is not already in use

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When I am trying to create a kafka connector with the name which is already in use through rest call, I got a error saying,

> {"error_code":409,"message":"Connector Test already exists"}

I want to bypass this error , for example while creating kafka Topic we have something like below,

```
./kafka-topics **--if-not-exists**  --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor  1 --partitions 1  --topic test
```

Do we have something like `--if-not-exists`  while creating kafka connectors?

Answer (score 4):

The way I like to do it us to use the `PUT` method to the config endpoint, like this:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
http://localhost:8083/connectors/my-connector-name/config -d "@my-connector-config.json"
```

The behavior is to create in case it doesn't exist and update otherwise, more in the documentation here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#put--connectors-(string-name)-config

Note that your `json` payload doesn't need to contain `name` and `config`, but only the `config` contents as in the docs example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way but you can always use the custom scripts to accomodate validation. 
You can use the REST API to query the active connectors like below.

```
 curl localhost:8083/connectors  // will return the active connectors on worker
 ["local-file-sink1", "db-sink1"]
```

Once you get the name of active connector, you can validate against your connector properties to see if the name is already is use or not.